# Call Intent.ACTION_PICK from tabHost and return to onActivityResult - How?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I've been searching around for a simple solution for this problem, but havent been able to find one, so here goes:

I have an app with a tabhost in it that controls a single webview. If tab 1 is pressed I make a javascript call in the webview etc. and that's how I control the content of this simple app.

Now I want to be able to launch the image/video gallery and pick some media, but this is causing me a headache. It's launched but when I chose some media the app just closes instantly (no force close, just disappears).

I've put a onActivityResult method in my app, but it isn't being called, and I do not know why.

This is some of my code (everything is in the same activity class):

```
mTabHost = getTabHost();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iphone)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.about)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.events)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Tab4", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.free)).setContent(R.id.webview));     
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test5").setIndicator("Tab5", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.video)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.getCurrentView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0)
            {
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                side1(mWebView);
            }
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1)
            {
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                side2(mWebView);
            }
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2)
            {
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                side3(mWebView);
            }
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 3)
            {
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                side4(mWebView);
            }
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 4)
            {
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                side5(mWebView);
                openStuff();
            }
        }       
    });     



public void openStuff()
{
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should convert your chain of if statements into a switch.

Answer (score 0):

In this your problem you have to write your code in onResume() method instead of onActivityResult. for the manage pro-pare logic you have to maintain flags in each tabs and write onResume method for all.
eg:

```
@Override
     protected void onResume() {<br>
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub<br>
             super.onResume();<br>
     }
```

I think u know activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) :

```
steps : onCreate() - onDestroy()<br>
onStart() / onRestart() - onStop()<br>
onResume() - onPause()
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I dont follow.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint in the onResume method, but the code does not return to onResume after i've picked an image.

Comment: what u say? actually what u want & what happens?

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in the onResume method, but when I pick an image from the gallery the app just quits, it does not return to the onResume method like I would've thought it would do.

Comment: But what would I look for/do when onResume is called?